# Heat Map Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, colors, heatmap

I search for a algorithm to calculate a HeatMap algorithm. (Color Blue to Green to Blue) like the one here:

[image]

I have tried this algorithm:

```
   double colorValue = ((value - min) / (max - min));
    if (colorValue > 1) {
        colorValue = 1;
    }
    Color color = new Color(colorValue, 0, 1 - colorValue, 1);
```

So what i am doing:

I standardirize the value and calculate the Color by the shown algorithm.
The result are only colors from blue to red.

Can anyone show me how i can add more colors?

Thanks!

Comment: It's basically taking what you've got above and repeating it a few times.

Comment: Basically not, my algorithm does not produce a color like green. Of course that's because of the 0 for green value. But I do not know how to change this algorithm in order to create colors from red to green to blue.

Comment: Think of it as multiple different ranges, with each range having its own start and end colour, and each value being in one of those ranges.

Comment: I have thought about it but how to do the gradient of the colors? By the way: Thanks for very quick response!!

Comment: Do you think i can change the     
     Color color = new Color(colorValue, 0, 1 - colorValue, 1);
In order to get what i want`?

Comment: `Blue to Green to Blue` - *blue to green to red*? In RGB, it will be cumbersome (check below/above midrange ((min+max)/2); apply your approach using (0, colorValue, 1-colorValue) and (colorValue, 1-colorValue, 0), respectively): consider [Turo's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44745856/3789665).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using other Color Model:

Color.getHSBColor(float h, float s, float b)

h - the hue component
s - the saturation of the color
b - the brightness of the color

So with one parameter (hue) you go through all the colors

i tried in gimp: 240 is blue, 0 is read and you go through blue cyan green yellow to red, so you could use 240/255 to 0/255